# How to use a generated digit from a chronometer displayed in a UILabel as an Integer in the View Controller?

Tags: swift, uilabel, nstimer, chronometer

We used a chronometer using the method of NSTimer and we want to use the value that this one displays in a UILabel in the View Controller to do some other simple operations but it doesn't work.

Our code to transform it from String to Integer is:
var labelText : String = countingLabel.text!

Thank You! We are new in this (7 hours) and will greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

To convert the string to an int, just call:

`var timerInt = Int(labelText)`